# How to output data in YII2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm trying to follow this instruction: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#db-connection

I've created a database (MAMP server), connected to it (response 200), but nothing is output on a page.

db.php file:

```
return [
  // 'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',

  // test begin
  'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
  // test end

  'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2basic',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => 'root',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Code on github: https://github.com/rinatoptimus/yii-test/tree/master/basic

Comment: this is only for db connect  not output is given by this  .. you can use the named  connect (normally  Yii::$app->db ) for create ssql command or use active record feature  too you can take a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html   ..  ,  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html ..,  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods available for showing your data. One example is GridView:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        'created_at:datetime',
        // ...
    ],
]) ?>
```

This is how you could get a data provider in your Controller. Pass $dataProvider to your view:

```
$searchModel = new ModelSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

You can generate Models and ModelSearch models easily with [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html).

If you don't want to use models and dataproviders, make sure that you actually retrieve information from the database. You can use ActiveRecord `Model::find()->all()` or use the default Query `(new yii\db\Query())->from("table")->...->all()`.